# Jenkins | Trigger a build using SVN tag -parameterized build

Tags: jenkins

I have a project configured on jenkins(Windows machine).
we get request to do build using the tags every day, i was using the parametrized build option to select the specific tag from repository.
I was passing that parameter to SVN repository URL for code checkout, But its not accepting it.
This is what i have configured:
**List Subversion tags**

Name: SVNTAG

Repositroy Url : http://svn.book.com/tags/myprofile

**Source code Management**

Subversion

Repositroy URL : http://svn.book.com/tags/myprofile/%SVNTAG%

But giving error like : "tags/myprofile/%SVNTAG%" doesn't exist in the repository.

Can any one help , what is the correct way to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this %SVNTAG% use $SVNTAG

Repositroy URL : http://svn.book.com/tags/myprofile/$SVNTAG

Answer (score 0):

You get that while on Job Configuration page? That's not an error, that's a warning, as obviously at that time is has no idea what the value of `SVNTAG` is.

You can ignore that, and the job will still run fine.

But you should go to Jenkins Global Configuration (`/configure`), search for **Subversion** section, and check mark **Validate repository URLs up to the first variable name**